# OneSignal Notification Sound not playing on app open

Tags: android, laravel, onesignal, ionic5

i have an app that fires a OneSignal custom sounds notifications, it's works perfectly when app is running on background or simple closed, but when app is opened the alert when a notification entered it's displayed but not the sound, it's only happen with Android, iOS works perfectly, i work with Ionic 5 and OneSignal latest version, thanks

Comment: What is the version of android, 28+?

Comment: Hi @MostafaHarb sorry for late response, yes actually 8.1.0 on tested device and 27 on other

Comment: I think onesignal sound is not editable on sdk version 28+

Comment: if you are clearing notification on onnotificationreceived then it may cause the sound to not play.